# Suppressing console errors from bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a bash script that shows the biggest files
on my raspberry pi linux box

How can i suppress the console output of read errors on directories
like lost+found etc?

```
du / -Sh | sort -rh | head -n 15
```

Example output :

```
du: cannot access `/proc/2884/task/2884/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/2884/task/2884/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/2884/fd/4': No such file or directory
du: cannot access `/proc/2884/fdinfo/4': No such file or directory
248M    /mnt/pishare/ftp/ipcam
127M    /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf
125M    /usr/bin
101M    /var
78M     /usr/lib
71M     /usr/lib/chromium
68M     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/jre/lib
60M     /usr/share/icons/gnome
51M     /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/SystemFiles/Converters/Java
42M     /opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/10.0/SystemFiles/Kernel/Binaries/Linux-ARM
35M     /var/lib/apt/lists
35M     /var/cache/apt
34M     /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-7-oracle-armhf/lib
31M     /usr/lib/gcc/arm-linux-gnueabihf/4.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
du / -Sh 2>/dev/null | sort -rh | head -n 15
```

i.e. redirect stderr to null device in `du` command.